# bash dirs command and +N option

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to use the dirs command with the +N option. The manual says:

```
 dirs [-clpv] [+n] [-n]
          Without options, displays the list of currently remembered directories.  The default display is on a single line with directory names separated by spaces.   Direc-
          tories are added to the list with the pushd command; the popd command removes entries from the list.
          +n     Displays the nth entry counting from the left of the list shown by dirs when invoked without options, starting with zero.
```

dirs -v shows:
`0  /dir1/

1  /dir2/

2  /dir3/`

However, dir +n 1, dir +N 1, dir -v +n 1, dir -v +N 1 all give:

`bash: dirs: +n: invalid number

dirs: usage: dirs [-clpv] [+N] [-N]`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Taras

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `dirs +N` means that you actually have to put a number there:

```
$ dirs -v
 0  /usr/local
 1  /usr
 2  /etc/init.d
 3  /etc
 4  /
 5  ~

$ dirs +3
/etc
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look closely, you will see that the `n` is underlined, which means it's a variable, not a string that you type verbatim.

In this case, the `n` stands for any number

e.g. `dirs +1` or `pushd +1`.

Comment: Both correct - probably should have inown that :*)